# Override method of bootstrap Tooltip.prototype.fixTitle()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, bootstrap-tour

Hello I use the `Bootstrap tour` in my site and I would like to override following method

```
  Tooltip.prototype.fixTitle = function () {
    var $e = this.$element
    if ($e.attr('title') || typeof ($e.attr('data-original-title')) != 'string') {
      $e.attr('data-original-title', $e.attr('title') || '').attr('title', '')
    }
  }
```

Can you explain me how to override this one ?

If I don't write code of this function then my popover is working good. It shows me title as a set like

```
    {
        element:   '.modal-content .existing-attachments img:eq(2)',
        placement: 'top',
        title:     _t("Select Cover"),
        content:   _t("Select the approprite cover."),
        popover:   { fixed: true },
    },
```

But because of this function it doesn't show title as I set in options "`Select Cover`" ,it shows me title of image on which I want to set popover.

```
<img class="img img-responsive" src="/website_blog/static/src/img/library/woodtexture.jpg" alt="Wood Wall Texture" title="Wood Wall Texture">
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to all the prototype functions of Tooltip using `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype`